# Maintaining Chrome Mobile Emulation on New Tab or window

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have opened a website on chrome with mobile emulation for iPad. But when an internal links open a new tab, new tab doesn't maintain mobile emulation mode. Instead, it opens in normal desktop mode. How can we ensure that new tab opens in same mobile emulation mode?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this for internal testing / development purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an bug. See here on [chrome official Bug Site](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2126#c12)

Answer (score 2):

To maintain mobile emulation mode on internal links:

1. Open DevTools by `Right click`->`Inspect`. Turn on emulator
2. Go to Settings by pressing `F1`
3. Select Auto-open DevTools for pop-ups
   [image]

This does not work when you explicitly `Open in a new tab` by Right click

Comment: If you are unable to find this option in the dev tools settings, then search for it with `cmd + shift + p`

Answer (score 0):

To any quick visitors, according to Raj Kamal's referenced bug link, a *current workaround* is **switching to the new tab, and just refreshing**. Chrome will then activate mobile mode on that tab.